# Working on Internet explorer form in vba

Tags: excel, internet-explorer-11, vba

```
 </tr><tr IsParameterRow="true">
<td class="ParamLabelCell"><label for="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07_txtValue"><span>Enter Number</span></label></td><td class="ParamEntryCell" style="padding-right:0px;"><div id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07">
                                    <input name="ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl07$txtValue" type="text" size="30" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07_txtValue" disabled="disabled" class="DisabledTextBox" />
                                </div></td>
                            </tr>
```

for the above HTML code I am unable to feed number in vba. please suggest.
below is the VBA code for inputting data.

```
sub my()
Dim IE As Object
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate Link
Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop
IE.document.getElementsById("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07_txtValue") = 12345
End Sub()




<td class="ParamLabelCell"><label for="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_txtValue"><span>Enter Start Date Here</span></label></td><td class="ParamEntryCell" style="padding-right:0px;"><div id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03">
                                    <div onactivate="event.cancelBubble=true;" style="white-space:nowrap;">
                                        <input name="ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl03$txtValue" type="text" value="11/29/2015" size="28" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl03$txtValue\',\'\')', 0)" onkeypress="if (WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) == false) return false;" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_txtValue" disabled="disabled" class="DisabledTextBox" />&nbsp;<input src="/ReportServer/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Version=11.0.5058.0&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.calendar_disabled.gif" name="ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl03$ddDropDownButton" type="image" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddDropDownButton" alt="Select a value" title="Select a value" style="cursor:pointer;" disabled="disabled" />
                                    </div>
                                </div></td>
```

I have another input box for date but the same thing I m using for date box. Its showing error "Object doesnot support this property or method

```
 IE.document.getElementById("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03").Value = sdate
```

where sdate contain current date

Comment: try `IE.document.getElementById("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07").Item(0) = 12345`

Comment: `IE.document.getElementById("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07_txtValue").value = "12345"`

Comment: I have another input box for date but the same thing I m using for date box. Its showing error "Object doesnot support this property or method"

Answer (score 0):

```
IE.Document.getElementById("ctl32_ctl04_ctl03_txtValue").value = SDate
```